# How to sort sum digits from the following list

Tags: python, list, sorting, sum, digits

```
list1 = [1236,985,150,641876,167]
```

I want to know how to sorted by sum digits **or** sorted by last digit in Python.

Output sorted by sum of digits in ascending order:

```
[150,1236,167,985,641876]
```

Comment: Unclear what you're asking, and way too broad, for noting.

Comment: So....What output are you expecting here? Where is your attempt? Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: [output]                                                                                                    
Sorted by sum of digits in ascending order:
[150,1236,167,985,641876]

Comment: @PluvialisPulchritudo Use `sorted(list1, key = lambda x: sum([int(i) for i in str(x)]))`

Comment: Or `sorted(list1, key = lambda x: sum(map(int,str(x))))`

Comment: `list1.sort(key=sum_of_digits)

def sum_of_digits(n):
    s = 0
    while n:
     s += n %10
     n = n // 10
    return s`

Comment: I think I understand your question: Here's a sum of digits sort: `list1.sort(key=lambda n: sum(int(d) for d in str(n)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorting list items considering unit's place. You can try:

```
list1 = [1236,985,150,641876,167] 
sorted(list1, key=lambda n: n%10)
[150, 985, 1236, 641876, 167]
```